# NoClassDefFound error in talend

Tags: talend

My sample job showing follwing error. What could be the problem.
[image]

Comment: Please mention the reason for down vote!!

Comment: Please refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This job has unresolved compilation error. Look at the "Problems" tab for issues.